# ggplot2: Use column names as x-axis and retain original order

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am making a grouped bar graph with my columns as the x-axis, the values as the y axis and the row names as colors. I would like to keep the axis organized the same as the dataframe. I have found many answers on how to convert columns to factors to prevent alphabetization, but I cannot figure out how to do this with column names.

```
perSample <- data.frame(miRNAnotPresent = c(1,5,10,4,12),
                        miRNApresent = c(12,23,19,24,15),
                        miRNAover1000 = c(5,8,1,13,2),
                        miRNAover10000 = c(1,3,10,2,11))
row.names(perSample) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

perSample$sample <- row.names(perSample)
df.p3 <- pivot_longer(data = perSample, 
                      cols = -sample,
                      names_to = "reads", 
                      values_to = "numberOfSamples")
p3 <- ggplot(df.p3, aes(x=reads, y=numberOfSamples, fill=sample)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip() +  
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position ="none")
```

Comment: Try with `ggplot(df.p3, aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(reads), y=numberOfSamples, fill=sample))`. `forcats::fct_inorder` will set the order of categories in the order as they appear in your data.

Comment: @stefan. This is worth for an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefans solution of `ggplot(df.p3, aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(reads), y=numberOfSamples, fill=sample)). forcats::fct_inorder` worked perfectly.